# mms sent/recive date is always in 1970

Tags: android

from below code i am able to get the MMS but the date is always wrong. might be i am doing something wrong while conversion.

```
   Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms"),null,null,null,date DESC);
count = cursor.getCount();
if (count > 0) {
  cursor.moveToFirst();
    long messageId = cursor.getLong(0);
   long timestamp = cursor.getLong(2);
   Date date = new Date(timestamp);
   String subject = cursor.getString(3);
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just some change.

long timestamp = cursor.getLong(2) * 1000;

Comment: Seems to be a stupidy of googles implementation, for sms you don't need this. Weird.

Comment: Unbelievably stupid!  I lost a lot of time on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Check you device or emulator's date.. when ever you reset your phone the date sets back to 1970.

you can enable the Automatic(network provided values) in date ant time settings to avoid this issue.