# Android MMS database, select rows by date from a mystery column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am accessing Android MMS database to get the date of MMS message:

```
Uri mmsUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/");
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = {"_id", "date"};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(mmsUri, projection, null, null, null);

long dateVal = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
//This date is always 1970
Date mmsDate = new Date(dateVal);
```

But the date I get is always 1970. Then, I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562025/mms-sent-recive-date-is-always-in-1970) for this. I need to set the `projection` to `null` (to return all columns) and then use the following code to get date value:

```
//A mystery column of index 2
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(2) * 1000;
//It works !
Date mmsDate = new Date(timestamp);
```

Everything until here is fine. But, now instead of geting all rows from MMS database, I need to select those rows which were sent after a certain date, which means I need to use selection & selection argument. Something like:

```
String selection = NAME_OF_MYSTERY_COLUMN_IDX_2 > minDate
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(mmsUri, projection, selection, null, null);
```

But I have no idea what is the name of the column with index 2, how could I achieve what I need ? Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Mike M. just run my code sample, you will see, "date" column always returns Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970. By the way, my device is Android 4.4.3. As I also have a link in my post, it is not only me have this problem.

Comment: @Mike M, yes, you are right, "date" returns correct value after I multiplied it by 1000. Please make an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code block is correct, except for the `Date` instantiation. That constructor expects the time in milliseconds, but the MMS table keeps dates in seconds. To correct this, simply multiply the value returned from the query by 1000.

```
Date mmsDate = new Date(dateVal * 1000);
```

For future reference, the `Cursor#getColumnName()` method will give you the String name for a given column index.

Comment: Good point! This answer is better than the answer I linked. Thanks @Mike M.!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
String selection =  "date_sent" > minDate
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.BaseMmsColumns.html#DATE_SENT

Comment: This is the same as "date" column, always returns me Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970